# Swift: Two different UITableViews with same tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have two tables, let's say tableA and tableB. Initially tableA is shown and tableB is hidden. Then when a user swipes right, table B is shown and tableA is hidden and so on. Now I need to have a tableHeaderView which would include name, photo etc, let's call it awesomeView. I need it on top for both the tables. In the previous version of the app, I wasn't including this awesomeView in the table so it was all fine. But now, I have to include it in the header as I have to scroll it up and when the scroll goes beyond the name, I have to show the name in the navigation bar.

**Attempt 1:**

I set the tableHeaderView of tableA and tableB to awesomeView, tableA headerView will obviously show blank, and tableB works properly.

**Attempt 2:**

I set just the tableHeaderView of tableA to awesomeView on viewDidLoad. Then when user swipes right I set tableB's tableHeaderView to awesomeView. This works fine initially but then table A goes blank after coming back from table B.

**Attempt 3:**

I tried the same as attempt 2 but now I also tried removing the particular awesomeView from respective tables but got the same outcome.

I know the possibility of duplicating awesomeView to have two such views and assigning to each table, but that is just too much redundancy. Them designers!

Comment: Sounds like you might want to restructure the design?

When you currently "swipe" are you "pushing" UITableViewController "B" onto the navigation stack, and then "popping" back to UITableViewController "A" on left swipe? Or do you have both A and B tables as subviews, and you're sliding them left/right?

Comment: Both the tables are already added as subviews and on swipe I'm just hiding/unhiding them.

Comment: Hmmm.. For Attempt 2... if it "works fine" to give awesomeView to A, then on swipe give it to B, it seems like the problem going *back* to A should be solvable... Otherwise, you can copy the view via code, and put one copy in each table.